# Tricks, Multiply across Subset - Left Coset Multiplication iff Normal - Fraleigh p. 138 Theorem 14.4

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

[Left coset multiplication is well defined by $(aH)(bH) = (ab)H \iff H \triangle G$.](http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/jonpak/N3.pdf)

Given $H\leq   G$, we wish to define a group structure on $G/H$ under suitable conditions. The natural way to do this is to define $ g_{1}H\star g_{2}H=g_{1}g_{2}H
$ for all $g_{1}$, $g_{2}\in H$.
Unfortunately in order for ⋆ to induce a binary operation on G/H, we
must show that it is a well-defined operation on left cosets. The definition
given above relies too heavily on the representatives $g_1, g_2$ to be well-defined
in general. Thus if $g_iH = g_i'H$ for $i = 1,2$, we must find conditions so that $g_1
g_2H = g_1'
g_2'H.$

> (5.) What's the flaw or defect here? How is it that 'the definition given above relies too heavily...'?? I know a function $f$ is well-defined:  $a = b \implies f(a) = f(b)$.

Now since $g_{i}H=g_{i}'H$, by Proposition 2.4 write $g_{i}=g_{i}'h_{i}$ for
$h_{i}\in H, i=1,2.$
Then $g_{1}g_{2}=(g_{1}'h_{1})(g_{2}'h_{2})=g_{1}'\color{blue}{g_{2}'\quad(g_{2}')^{-1}}h_{1}g_{2}'h_{2} \quad (☼)$.

> (1.) How do you preordain to use this trick $\color{blue}{g_{2}'(g_{2}')^{-1}}$ in blue?   Before doing this trick, you don't know if  $\color{blue}{(g_{2}')^{-1}}h_{1}g_{2}'h_{2} \in H$, hence where does it spring from?
>   By means of anon's answer, I know we want (things $\in G)H$.

Thus $g_{1}g_{2}H=g_{1}'g_{2}'H \iff (☼) \iff \color{blue}{(g_{2}')^{-1}}h_{1}g_{2}'h_{2} \in H \; \forall \; g_{2}'\in G$, $h_{1}$, $h_{2}\in H$.$ \iff \color{blue}{(g_{2}')^{-1}}h_{1}g_{2}' \quad h_{2}\color{magenta}{{h_2}^{-1}} \in H $ for all $g_2\in G$, $h_1\in H \quad (♥)
$
For convenience, you can chuck the subscripts by calling $g_2 = g$ and $h_2 = h$.

Since inclusion (♥) holds for all $g_2 \in G$, replace $g_2$ with $g^{-1}$ $\iff gHg^{-1}\subseteq H \iff \color{green}{g^{-1}}gHg^{-1}\color{green}{g} \subseteq \color{green}{g^{-1}}H\color{green}{g} \iff H\subseteq g^{-1}Hg$.
Using this with inclusion (♥) gives $g^{-1}Hg=H$ for all $g\in G$ $\iff$ $H$ is normal in $G$.

> (2.) How do you preordain the trick to multiply by $\color{magenta}{{h_2}^{-1}}$?
>
> (3.) Why are [you](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/72794/53934) authorized to multiply $\color{green}{g^{-1}, g}$ across a subset?
>
> (4.) What's the 'desired kind of expression' in anon's answer? What's 'the "extra" bit left over'?

Answer (score 1):

(1) Often we have a desired kind of expression, but we might be okay with an "extra" bit left over. In this case, say you want $g_1'g_2'$ in front, but only $g_1'$ is there to begin with, so do the well-known "add and subtract the same thing" trick (only now with group structure) inside the expression.

(2) How would you solve $2x+1=0$ for $x$? You'd subtract $1$, then divide by $2$. When the stuff of interest is on the inside of an expression and we want to isolate it, we peel off the outer layers. In this case, $h_2$ is on the outside, and can be peeled off because it's in $H$.

(3) You don't need anyone's permission; nobody's stopping you. Left-multiplying a subset of a group by a group element is a special case of applying a function to sets; if $f$ is a function defined on a set $A$ and $B\subseteq A$ then $f(B)\subseteq f(A)$ follows easily.

Notice in the first two points the inspiration is from techniques and heuristics used in intermediate algebra, and the third one is a basic fact of elementary set theory, so reverse-engineering how the steps in the proofs are chosen shouldn't require any novel group-theory-type thinking that a student hasn't already been exposed to at some point, although they *do* require thinking!

Comment: @FrankMuer As my answer says, "say you want $g_1'g_2'$ in front."

Comment: Thanks. I'm still confounded. Can you please notify me about my new update (5.)?